# Does the surrounding spacetime around a Black Hole look the same from all directions in space?

Tags: black-holes

The reason I ask is because I really don't understand what "black hole" means in the context of being a spherical object whose weight distends space.    Is space some elastic substance that can snap back to the way it was pre-black hole? I can't seem to find a picture of a flat rubber space time surface that is stretched by a black hole that doesn't seem to make it look like it can only be seen from the 'top.'

Comment: What type of "black hole" are you talking about? Schwarzschild, Kerr-Newman, something else?

Comment: *Weight* is a force, and gravitational distortion is due to *mass*, which is not a force.

Comment: You simply aren't going to find a good 2-dimensional representation of a unique, 3-dimensional phenomenon. The 2-d rubber mat representation is good up to a point, but not completely adequate. Being 2-D, it wouldn't make much sense to look at the rubber mat from any direction except the top, but that isn't really a good indicator of how space itself warps.

Comment: Newton's first law says an object at rest or in uniform motion remains at rest or in uniform motion unless acted on by a force. Normally, something at rest just sits there and something in uniform motion moves in a straight line. When we say gravity curves space, what we mean is that it redefines what it means for something at rest to just sit there and it redefines what a straight line looks like for something in uniform motion. There's no good analog to anything you might experience in everyday life, so don't expect to find a good analogy

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking about images like this,[image: black hole as a sheet]which attempt to show space as a flat sheet and massive objects as, well, massive objects weighing down the sheet. The problem is that black holes are spherical, and should look the same from all directions. Clearly, this image does not!

The solution to this seeming contradiction is that these images are *not* pictures of black holes, or simulations of what they would look like. They are analogies. And like any analogy, they are a little bit wrong.
[image: An attempts at explaining spacetime.]
The reason for even having picture with the sheet is that black holes exist in 3 spacial dimensions. When we draw our picture, however, we only have two. We can use the trick of perspective to make the abstraction appear three dimensional, but one of those dimensions has to be used represent the curvature, to give an explanation as to why objects are "attracted" to black holes, massive or not. Imagine you roll a ball on that rubber sheet somewhere to to the right of the center. Even if you roll it directly towards the top of the picture, it will curve to the left. Just make sure you know that the abstraction isn't perfect.

If you were out somewhere in space and saw a Schwarzschild black hole, it might look something like this. 
[image: black hole painting]
Although this is hard to imagine, it would actually look this way from any direction. There are other types of black holes that are not spherically symmetric, such as a rotating (Kerr) black hole. Let's just stick with static uncharged (Schwarzschild) black holes though. However, if it has a star or many stars nearby, as (some? many? most?) do, it will have an accretion disk, which would look this.
[image: accretion disk]
This is no longer spherically symmetric because the surrounding mass breaks the spherical symmetry. A non-rotating black hole with nothing around would look the same from any direction though.

Comment: Great answer, but I have to make a nitpick:  a "black hole with nothing around" might still be rotating, which would break the perfect spherical symmetry and would cause it to look different from different directions.

Comment: An addition I would include is that a black hole is 3D, but in order to draw the curvature of space, we must also use one of those dimensions in our drawing.  We just don't have enough dimensions to make art that represents all the aspects of the black hole, that's why it looks like the black hole has a top.   Also, that funnel shape represents something abstract, not a literal depiction.  What that caveat, you could try imagining that funnel shape happening in all directions simultaneously, and the scientist just draws one for the sake of reducing clutter.

Comment: I hope those edits address both issues. Also, can someone correct me on how often black holes have accretion disks?